# SQL table join many-to-many very slow

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, many-to-many

Using PostgreSQL, I'm joining around 10 tables in a query, all of them being many-to-many relationships. The DB is still very small at the moment (hundreds of rows in total, all tables combined), but the query is extremely slow (1+ min processing time).

As every join multiplies the number of rows (joining 2 tables having 5 records each will yield 25 rows), the result quickly becomes huge with more than 300,000 rows. The query is in the following form :

```
select * from student_profile sp
  join student_profile_skills sps on sp.id = sps.student_profile_id
  join student_profile_hobby sph on sp.id = sph.student_profile_id
  --and other 8 similar joins
  where sp.id = 1;
```

The tables are straightforward (junction tables with 2 FKs). What's the recommended practice here ? Is it the query that has to be written in a more optimized way, or use separate queries ? Thx in advance !

Additional info :

```
CREATE TABLE student_profile
(
  id                       serial  NOT NULL,
  first_name               text    NOT NULL,
  last_name                text    NOT NULL,
  country_id               integer,
  city_id                  integer,
  faculty_id               integer,
  university_id            integer,
  degree_id                integer,
  degree_year              integer,
  created_at               timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at               timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_pkey               PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_country_id_fkey    FOREIGN KEY (country_id)    REFERENCES country (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_city_id_fkey       FOREIGN KEY (city_id)       REFERENCES city (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_faculty_id_fkey    FOREIGN KEY (faculty_id)    REFERENCES faculty (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_university_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (university_id) REFERENCES university (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_degree_id_fkey     FOREIGN KEY (degree_id)     REFERENCES degree (id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_profile_skill
(
  id                 serial                   NOT NULL,
  student_profile_id integer                  NOT NULL,
  skill_id           integer                  NOT NULL,
  position           integer                  NOT NULL,
  created_at         timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at         timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_skill_pkey                    PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_skill_student_profile_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (student_profile_id) REFERENCES student_profile (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_skill_skill_id_fkey           FOREIGN KEY (skill_id)           REFERENCES skill (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_skill_unique                  UNIQUE (student_profile_id, skill_id),
  CONSTRAINT student_profile_skill_position_unique         UNIQUE (student_profile_id, position)
);
```

Comment: Can you show some query and/or table details?

Comment: You need to give us the tables DDLs

Comment: The query is in the form of : select * from student_profile sp join student_profile_skills sps on sp.id = sps.student_profile_id join student_profile_hobby sph on sp.id = sph.student_profile_id (and other 8 similar joins) where sp.id = 1;

Comment: Are all join columns (i.e. id and _id columns) indexed?

Comment: What's the business question? Why do you think you need a result set like this? For a single student it's like a cross join.

Comment: So the business question is to load the student profile with his skills, languages, etc. There are around 10 of these concepts, which have to be available on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended practice in almost all many-to-many connections is to split them up to one-to-many/many-to-one. However,  you have 1-to-many tables in a 3 way join that results in an insane amount of **repeating** records if your students have more than 1 skill/hobby.

Example of a 3 way join where you have 1 student with 2 skills and 1 hobby:

```
Student     Skill       Hobby  
Smith J.    Linguistic  Fishing  
Smith J.    Profiling   Fishing
```

I would suggest 1 of 2 options:

1. **Only** select the values you need when you need them, (because I can't imagine you needing a table with both hobbies and skills. For instance: Separate views for hobbies and skills.
2. Create a script for a temporary table where you write up all skills into 1 field and all hobbies into another. (You'll probably need to use cursors to build them, so keep in mind you don't want to rebuild them often).

Comment: Thx for your response ! So it means I should rather use separate SQL queries (ex : select * from student_profile_skill where student_profile_id = 1) and assemble the data in the backend code (Node.js) instead of joining all of these tables ?

Comment: Yes, unless you have a very specific requirement to have the duplicate records (which is unlikely). If you're putting the results into a website or a piece of software you simply use 1 join at a time to display results in specific forms, or if you need a single line to display all skills/hobbies of 1 student you'll need to create another table and use a cursor to create an entry in new table for each student and add text description of your skill/hobby in corresponding fields of a table.